# What is the best way to read large datasets with less latency for torch model?

Tags: deep-learning, torch

I am familiar to use some data specific layers or tools by the habits of my in use libraries like mxnet (recordIO), caffe(LMDB). They also handle data augmentation tricks as well. I decided to give a shot for Torch to see what is good or bad. From the initial gaze, there is no such data loading standard for Torch or I am missing it. Could you point some good ways to load large scale datasets for my model training?

Comment: What did you end up using?

Comment: @MortezaShahriariNia I used fb.resnet approach below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some pointers:

- [twitter/torch-dataset](https://github.com/twitter/torch-dataset)
- [fb.resnet.torch/dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/fb.resnet.torch/blob/8f433818e9466a049d8844ae4462569ae38e5a61/dataloader.lua)
- [Element-Research/dataload](https://github.com/Element-Research/dataload)

More resources can also be found in the [torch7/wiki](https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Cheatsheet#loading-popular-datasets-).